# Disable over-permissive behavior of DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime, format

Given an invalid date in the format `MMDD`, say `1332`, the `DateTime::createFromFormat` method in PHP 5.3.0+ will accept it as a valid date, `0201` in that same `MMDD` format.

Code snippet:

```
$dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat("md", "1332");

if ($dateobj) {
  print $dateobj->format('Y/m/d H:i:s') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2019/02/01 20:59:37
```

Obviously, `13` is not a valid month of the year and `32` is not a valid day of any month. It's also apparent that `DateTime::createFromFormat` is "rolling over" those numbers, as if it were adding 13 months and 32 days to a zero value (the current datetime's year). One month after December (month 12) is January (in this case month "13"), and 32 days after January 1 (inclusive) is February 1.

Is there a way to still use `DateTime::createFromFormat` but disable, override, or otherwise work around that specific over-permissive behavior?

Comment: Open the manual and have a gander. You might [be amazed at what you find](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php).

Comment: @tadman I did see that before I decided to go with `createFromFormat`. The issue with using `checkdate` is that not all my inputs have a year, not all of them are integer values, and the format of the input isn't consistent. I'd have to use `createFromFormat` (or something similar) and _then_ `checkdate`. I'll try to edit my question so it's more specific.

Comment: How are you using `createFromFormat` if the input dates don't all have the same format?

Comment: @tadman The `checkdate` man page did actually have a user comment with a `createFromFormat`-only solution. I added that as the answer, but if that's what you had in mind I can remove it and have you answer with it.

Comment: @Barmar I have multiple calls to `createFromFormat` inside `if` statements that only set the return value if a `DateTime` object is successfully created.

If `DateTime::createFromFormat("md", "12/31");` fails, `DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d", "12/31");` will succeed.

Comment: Maybe you should be using regular expressions to test if the input is in a particular format. That would allow you to extract the pieces, which you could then pass to `checkdate()`.

Comment: @Barmar Regex is an option. It might get complicated with the dozen or so different formats, though. All the input formats do happen to fit nicely with the format characters used by `createFromFormat` so it's cleaner looking, and that way I'm also not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: But if you try to use `checkdate` after `createFromFormat` you're going to have to extract the fields from the date somehow, and a regexp is likely to be the easiest way. So it's either `createFromFormat` then regexp then `checkdate`, or regexp then `checkdate` then `createFromFormat`.

Comment: But your `createFromFormat` then `format` solution looks very clean, it's easy to put it into a function.

Comment: @bmedev You can't verify a date without a year. February 29th may or may not be a valid date. In more exotic circumstances entire days have gone missing, like [when Samoa changed time zones](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-13334229).

Comment: @tadman In general, that is true. In my case, I truly don't care about the year. As long as February 29th is valid in _any_ year, it's valid for my purposes. If the next Samoa loses a day, that doesn't matter either. That lost day is still valid in other years. If neo-Samoa removes December 30th from _every_ year, it's no longer following the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: So long as you're aware of the risks. Sometimes [really big companies forget](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/blog/2009/jan/01/zune-firmware-mistake).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to use `DateTime::createFromFormat`, and it alone, is to compare the `DateTime` object it created to the original input:

```
$dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);

if ($dateobj && $dateobj->format($format) == $date) {
  print($dateobj->format($format));
}
```

If they're the same, the input date is valid. If they're not the same, `DateTime::createFromFormat` did its "rollover" calculation and you have an invalid input date.

This was actually a solution given on the [`checkdate` PHP Manual page as a User Contributed Note](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205), though it doesn't involve `checkdate` itself.